# linking libmedia_jni.so coudn't find the header android_media_MediaCodec.h

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-mediacodec, android.mk

I'm trying to link libmedia_jni.so in my android project so that I could access android_media_MediaCodec.h, but It fails to find the header.

my .cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <media/android_media_MediaCodec.h>
```

and Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := AndroidMediaCodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AndroidMediaCodec.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := libmedia_jni

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I just want to link the library, because I don't have the whole framework. Is that even possible?